# Jenkins error when saving job configurations

Tags: jenkins

I finished just to configure some buildjobs. But when i clicked apply / save (doesn't matter, because the same error appears) the following error shows up. Changes are saved somehow and the configuration page for this jobs loads frustrating long afterwards. What could be the reason and how to fix it?

**ERROR Message**

```
HTTP Status 500 - An attempt was made to write more data to the response headers than there was room available in the buffer. Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector or write less data into the response headers.

type Exception report

message An attempt was made to write more data to the response headers than there was room available in the buffer. Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector or write less data into the response headers.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.coyote.http11.HeadersTooLargeException: An attempt was made to write more data to the response headers than there was room available in the buffer. Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector or write less data into the response headers.
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.checkLengthBeforeWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:546)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.write(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:510)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.write(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:427)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.sendHeader(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:393)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.prepareResponse(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1495)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:767)
    org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:174)
    org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:365)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:345)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:303)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:108)
    com.jcraft.jzlib.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:122)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.FilterServletOutputStream.close(FilterServletOutputStream.java:36)
    net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletOutputStream.close(FilterServletOutputStream.java:45)
    java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(Unknown Source)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(Unknown Source)
    java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(Unknown Source)
    java.io.BufferedWriter.close(Unknown Source)
    org.dom4j.io.XMLWriter.close(XMLWriter.java:286)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.HTMLWriterOutput.close(HTMLWriterOutput.java:70)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:56)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:95)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.ResponseImpl.forward(ResponseImpl.java:121)
    hudson.model.AbstractModelObject.sendError(AbstractModelObject.java:70)
    hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:1167)
    hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:786)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1531.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.S
```

Comment: Are you using an old version of Jenkins? We had similar issues in the past (not always) and an upgrade to our Jenkins fixed it!

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.549 and latest release is 1.563.
Maybe a update could fixe it... hope dies last :D

Comment: Also make sure to update your plugins... one of the might be the culprit!

Comment: Just updated all plugins -> it did not help. BUT I think i found the reason: i have uninstalled the Plugin „Publish over SSH“ and it helped for now. System update will be done soon too. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If it solves the problem, post an answer to your own question with the solution, so others can find it and enjoy it.

Comment: I will do so the next days... but first i need to verify that the problem is fixed and does not come back right after i gave an answear :D

Comment: as I mentioned: it did not help after all. Updated now to the newest version of Jenkins and hope every thing will be better now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read the comments to my question above.

"Just updated all plugins -> it did not help. BUT I think i found the reason: i have uninstalled the Plugin „Publish over SSH“ and it helped for now. System update will be done soon too. Thank you for your help."

-> The deinstallation solved the problem not. The server went a little bit faster afterwards, but not as much as expected and hoped.

Now i have updated to the newest version of Jenkins and hope that it will fix my issues.